# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.299.00' Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a Django views.py file, where I both render a page and create objects based on a model. The data for creating these objects come from a function from a python file (price.py) which I imported.

For some reason, when I run the script by itself, I am able to convert a string to a float (the value would be something like '4124.3123'). However, running this exact code as an import results in a value error.

So my file structure looks something like this:

```
app
    views.py
    price.py
    models.py
    urls.py
```

Error:

```
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/joe/Documents/pcbuilder/cpu/views.py", line 40, in homepage
    itemlist = canada('https://www.canadacomputers.com/index.php?cPath=4_64')
  File "/home/joe/Documents/pcbuilder/cpu/price.py", line 57, in canada
    PRICES = [float(str(i).split('>')[-3].strip('<strong/>').replace('*','').replace(',','.')[1:]) for i in PRICE]
  File "/home/joe/Documents/pcbuilder/cpu/price.py", line 57, in <listcomp>
    PRICES = [float(str(i).split('>')[-3].strip('<strong/>').replace('*','').replace(',','.')[1:]) for i in PRICE]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.299.00'
```

Here is the bothersome list comprehension from my price.py:

```py
def canada():
# some code

    PRICES = [float(str(i).split('>')[-3].strip('<strong/>').replace('*','').replace(',','.')[1:]) for i in PRICE]

#some code

#return type: dictionary
```

And here is my views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import cpu
from django.template import loader
import os
import django
from .price import canada

def createobject(graph):
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','pcbuilder.settings')

    import django
    django.setup()



    def add_data(data1, data2, data3):
        d, created = cpu.objects.get_or_create(item=data1, price=data2,website=data3)
        print("- Data: {0}, Created: {1}".format(str(d), str(created)))
        return d

    add_data('h','h','h')

    for i in graph:
        add_data(str(i), str(graph[i]), 'canada computers')






def homepage(request):

    print('Receiving CPUs')

    itemlist = canada('https://www.canadacomputers.com/index.php?cPath=4_64')

    print('Received CPUs')

    createobject(itemlist)


    items = cpu.objects.all
    template = loader.get_template('cpu.html')
    context = {
        'items': items,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

NOTE: canada() is a function in price.py

Comment: We would have to see what your HTML looks like, but the error is pretty descriptive. A value with two decimal points is not a valid float. In the case of the number '1.299.00`, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @C.Nivs Oh wait derp, you're right. I have no idea how I missed that. It works now, I just do a .replace(',','').